# Color US counties on US map using a numeric variable for color intensity

Tags: r, maps, geospatial, choropleth

I have a data frame 'mydata.final' (see below) that contains US counties and a continuous numeric variable 'Mean.Wait' that ranges from zero to 10 or so. I also created variable 'wait' that is based on the 'Mean.Wait' and takes on discrete values from 1 (lowest values on 'Mean.Wait') to 5 (highest values on 'Mean.Wait').

I can create a map of the US with the counties colored based on the values of 'wait' using R package 'maps':

```
######################################################################
### Generating an artificial data file:
######################################################################

library(maps)
mydata.final <- data.frame(county = (map('county', plot = FALSE)$names),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)

### My numeric variable:
set.seed(123)
mydata.final$Mean.Wait <- runif(nrow(mydata.final)) * 10

### Introducing NAs to mimic my real data set:
set.seed(1234)
mydata.final$Mean.Wait[sample(1:nrow(mydata.final), 1500)] <- NA

### Cutting the original numeric variable into categories
### because I don't know how to color based on 'Mean.Wait':
mydata.final$wait <- cut(mydata.final$Mean.Wait, breaks = 5)
levels(mydata.final$wait) <- 1:5
mydata.final$wait <- as.numeric(as.character(mydata.final$wait))

######################################################################
### Building a US map based on 'wait' (5 categories)
######################################################################

### Creating my 5 colors:
pal <- colorRampPalette(c("yellow", "red"))
allcolors <- pal(5)

### Looking at my 5 colors:
barplot(1:5, rep(1,5), col = allcolors, horiz = T)

### Builiding the US map using 5 categories in 'wait':
map('county', fill = TRUE, col = allcolors[mydata.final$wait],
            resolution = 0, lty = 0, bg = "transparent")
map('state', lwd=1, add=TRUE)
```

My goal is: instead of splitting 'Mean.Wait' into 5 ordered categories ('wait'), I'd like to color the counties on the map based on the intensity of my (continuous) 'Mean.Wait'. What would be the way to do it and maybe even to add a legend? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you provide data for perhaps one state and its counties, and whatever else would allow us to run a reproducible sample of your code on that state [assuming it reproduces your problem]?

Answer (score 0):

You asked this question also on R-help on April 2nd.  Here were the answers.

You could use `colorRamp()` and `rgb()` to get more continuous colors.
For example

```
newpal <- colorRamp(c("yellow", "red"))
missing <- is.na(mydata.final$Mean.Wait)
newcol <- ifelse(missing, "white",

rgb(newpal(mydata.final$Mean.Wait[!is.na(mydata.final$Mean.Wait)]/
                                  max(mydata.final$Mean.Wait,
na.rm=T)), maxColorValue=255))
map('county', fill=TRUE, col=newcol,
    resolution=0, lty=0, bg="transparent")
map('state', lwd=1, add=TRUE)
```

You can also try the color.scale function in plotrix, which allows you to
specify the NA color in the call.

```
library(plotrix)   newcol<-color.scale(mydata.final$Mean.Wait,extremes=c("yellow","red"),na.color="white")
```